# putObject to Public S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an API invoked lambda that generates signed getObject and putObject URLs. GET and PUT on my restricted bucket (contains zip files) work fine, but PUT on my public bucket (contains images) returns a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error. There is no GET on the public bucket, images from that bucket are referenced directly. Do I need extra configuration to PUT on a public bucket? I've tried giving the most generous permissions I can think without luck.

**EDIT:** I did end up having to send in the specific image MIME type to the endpoint that generates the signed URL. image/* didn't work, unfortunately.

**Signed URL Generation (called by getSignedImgUploadUrl)**

```js
let params = {
    Bucket: "public-bucket",
    Key: `${folder}/${key}.jpg`, // Ideally without extension
    Expires: 30,
    ContentType: "image/jpeg", // Ideally image/*
    ACL: "public-read" // Tried with and without this
};
let url = s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", params);
let result = {
    signedUrl: url,
    key: key
};
return result;
```

**Use Signed URL**

```js
  public uploadImg(folder: string, file: any, key: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._spinnerService.spinObservable(
      new Observable(subscriber => {
        this.getSignedImgUploadUrl(folder, key)
          .subscribe(result => {
            // put to signedUrl fails with 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch
            this._httpClient.put(result["signedUrl"], file, { headers: { "x-amz-acl": "public-read" } })
              .subscribe(() => {
                subscriber.next(result["key"]);
                subscriber.complete();
              }, err => {
                console.log(err);
                subscriber.error(err);
              });
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
            subscriber.error(err);
          });
      }));
  }
```

**Lambda Role**

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::restricted-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*", (Ideally just getObject/putObject)
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::public-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Public Bucket Policy**

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::public-bucket/*"
        },
        // Also tried adding s3:* for the lambda role without luck
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1624999949645",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account:role/service-role/lambda-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::public-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the code that uploads the object?

Comment: Sure! I've added the code from the UI where I first get the signed url and then attempt to PUT the image to it. I recently tried with the acl headers, but that hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Try explicitly sending the `Content-Type` header on the client side.

Comment: Well... that totally worked. Why do you suppose the Content-Type is required client side for a public bucket/image types but not for zips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OP's comment, explicitly sending `Content-Type` HTTP header worked. The reason why this header is sometimes required is because the HTTP client cannot correctly infer the MIME type from the PUT payload.